# Is any simple formula to find impact of new value addition on total

Tags: arithmetic

Sorry for my poor math skills. Please down vote after stating the reason.

I have 4 values A, B, C and D. Following is the calculation.

$(A + B + C) - D = Total.$

Later any of $A,B,C$ or $D$ will replace with new value.

Eg: 
$A = 100$

$B = 200$

$C = 300$

$D = 200$

$(100 + 200 + 300) - 200 = 400$

New value of $A = 600$

What I have is **Total 400** and **Old A value 100** and **new A value 600**.

$(400 - 100) + 600 = 900$ //Output

Following is my current formula.

```
var newVal = 0;

if(not D){

   newVal = (net - prevVal) + newVal;

 }else{

 newVal = (net + prevVal) - newVal;

}
```

Is there any other way / formula to find the impact on total when replace an old value ?

Comment: This appears to be a programming problem and I suppose that is why the downvotes.

Comment: @Karl this is a silly question, that's why down votes . Why would anyone derive a formula for this problem, this is not even a problem.

Comment: Why? I don't know, but I think the jist of the problem is this. Having worked out a value for a formula is there a way of easily updating without wholesale recalculation. I don't think it is silly but is perhaps more programming. I agree it is a hard post to understand.

Comment: Karl - yes it is a programming problem. But when I posted in stakoverflow I got down vote, for them it is  a mathematic problem :D. thanks for the support :)

@ritwiksinha - yes it is a simple and idiotic problem but Im working on a big set of items. this is part of a big programming loop. I got the result with stated method but I want to know if there is any other method to find the result using - total, old value and new value. just confirm if no other methods :)

Comment: @PraveenVijayan Then you should post some more code for them to see. I rarely post on stack overflow because they down vote for no reason, they state reasons like find the problem yourself.

Comment: @ritwiksinha - This is not a code problem actually. It is an arithmetic problem. I solved the issue but I would like to know if I could solve the problem differently or this is the only way to solve the problem. Im seeking for a one liner like " total + (new value - old value)"

Comment: If you just care about readability then use ternary operator. **newVal = (!D) ? (net - prevVal) + newVal :  (net + prevVal) - newVal;**

Comment: Nope, readability is not an issue and its not about language too. Its a generic question. Thank you so much :)